# How can define default 'ng serve' parameters using angular.json?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl-nx

I have a monorepo setup with multiple Angular 9 applications (build by `nrwl nx`):

```
fontend-client
fronted-admin
```

I can easily start either of the applications with:

```
npm start frontend-client
npm start frontend-admin
```

However, in order to remotely debug the applications I need to pass additional parameters to `ng serve` and therefore these are the full commands:

```
npm start frontend-client -- --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
npm start frontend-admin -- --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

How can I save `—host` and `—disable-host-check` as default parameters in `angular.json`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by define a custom script in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
  "start-client": "ng serve frontend-client -- --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
  "start-admin": "ng serve frontend-admin-- --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
}
```

and in your command you can use:

```
npm run start-client
npm run start-admin
```

Comment: goog point! For completness sake, is there a way to define these parameters in angular.json?